# iOS Swift 5 replace segue not fully replacing

Tags: ios, swift

I have a fairly simple app which requires MSAL authentication. I have wired this up to a parent view controller and a child view controller to show after successful login.

I have a segue connected through storyboards and using code:

```
performSegue(withIdentifier:...)
```

All of this is working fine however when I trigger the segue I am still able to drag the new view down to go back to the previous view. iOS 13

How do I fully replace the old segue so that the only way to navigate back to the original view is by using the exit segue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it.

I needed to set the presentation to full screen not automatic.